# Scrape javascript table with beautifulSoup which loads table data everytime on click

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape search-intelligence.co. site contains javascript table which I'm trying to scrape using beautiful Soup. but I'm not getting in to table data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Er0e.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
url = 'https://search-intelligence.co.uk/niche-finder'
headers = {
   'value': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
   'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
   'cookie': '_ga=GA1.3.280184480.1658298012; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImxJbXN4NHpuRHRkSnB0RjNnMEU1cVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTEd6V3BibHEvTG84aCtkajIxQTJ4Szk4cTZQQ2dNODJmcHpSZkltK3FZQTJOOUIvSHJDU05EV3Ztd0tUMEJCbmhxTzVFSThoQ1NNaldDWWpGNEo1Z0ZsYjlUSTVEZVBJcGw5NmIrK2NqdHh2cURVTUJyQy9JcUdMYmNWZ1FwQ3MiLCJtYWMiOiI1ZmRjNDE4YWI4OTVhZDZkMjA1OTlhNGU5Zjk1YTNkMDQxNTQyNTc0MmU3MjhiMGE5NjM0YzFkY2Q0ZjQ1NmZjIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InJRSDVHMEFOY3BCcHk1OGNjY2srdGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiS1pxbEJJNHZtT3ZuNkgzMTlhTG1CZXBwY3VYK3JIamNaajhSU1JXRmpwS3lFMElFenpVdVpNd0Q0VlRQdFdUYi9ndFRGQytJcUxIV1pCUmxpVkEzTVRX`enter code here`SzZiOWFXVCs0ZHhGVldxbTRucGJjTjRNM0tQWHg4NUNUdk9aZUNxaGIiLCJtYWMiOiIwZTU0OTMzZTM1MDZkZmI5MjdjZmIzNDczNzViZGI4YzM1ODdhN2RiYzk0YzUzMzI3Njg1MjE4MTlmYzg4MmVlIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; _gid=GA1.3.1135025661.1662360353'
}
  
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

print (soup)
```

Am i missing something here?
table contains 100rows and 3188 pages. when clicked the second page it loads another 100rows of data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSg78.png)

Here's the result that I'm getting
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBAQh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in that table is being loaded dynamically, via an XHR call (you can see this by inspecting Network tab in browser's Dev tools).
EDIT: the following code will pull all websites (100k at once):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

headers = {
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'referer': 'https://search-intelligence.co.uk/niche-finder/',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

big_df = pd.DataFrame()
y=0
for x in tqdm(range(1, 5)):
    url = f'https://search-intelligence.co.uk/niche-finder/data-table?draw={x}&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=domain&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=domain&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=import_date&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=import_date&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=source&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=source&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=referring_domains&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=referring_domains&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=dr&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=dr&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=traffic&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=traffic&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=pages&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=pages&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start={y}&length=100000&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1662370391010'

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data'])
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    y = y + 100000
big_df = big_df.drop_duplicates()
print(big_df)
big_df.to_csv('all_that_jazz.csv')
```

This will save the data to csv,  and print out in terminal:

```
    id  domain  import_date processed   processed_date  source  referring_domains   dr  traffic created_at  updated_at  pages
0   66064   0-60specs.com   2022-05-10 15:53:50 1   2022-07-18T21:27:02.000000Z janetpanic-competitors  2,156   29  70,448  2022-05-10T15:53:50.000000Z 2022-07-18T21:27:02.000000Z 2,633
1   115705  0-jayparts.com  2022-05-12 20:33:18 1   2022-07-18T03:52:10.000000Z coinchefs-competitors   129 7   65  2022-05-12T20:33:18.000000Z 2022-07-18T03:52:10.000000Z 360,422
2   238990  000webhost.com  2022-05-14 20:56:52 1   2022-07-16T09:59:45.000000Z stackoverflow-competitors   110,073 91  20,503  2022-05-14T20:56:52.000000Z 2022-07-16T09:59:45.000000Z 752,768
3   120971  000webhostapp.com   2022-05-14 15:02:26 1   2022-07-18T02:02:28.000000Z enduringworld-competitors   161,883 89  2,266   2022-05-14T15:02:26.000000Z 2022-07-18T02:02:28.000000Z 8,031,647
4   160779  001.com.ua  2022-05-14 16:42:57 1   2022-07-17T12:32:44.000000Z flightpedia-competitors 198 5   1   2022-05-14T16:42:57.000000Z 2022-07-17T12:32:44.000000Z 54,885
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
318708  123365  zzyzxphile.com  2022-05-14 15:04:42 1   2022-07-18T01:14:48.000000Z enduringworld-competitors   30      17  2022-05-14T15:04:42.000000Z 2022-07-18T01:14:48.000000Z 35
318709  256096  zzz.buzz    2022-05-14 21:20:55 1   2022-07-16T04:05:42.000000Z microeducate-tech-competitors   411 27  230 2022-05-14T21:20:55.000000Z 2022-07-16T04:05:42.000000Z 546
318710  100706  zzzensleep.com  2022-05-11 12:18:43 1   2022-07-18T09:12:10.000000Z eachnight-competitors   19      12  2022-05-11T12:18:43.000000Z 2022-07-18T09:12:10.000000Z 170
318711  99171   zzzquil.com 2022-05-11 12:16:42 1   2022-07-18T09:46:15.000000Z eachnight-competitors   609 47  138,404 2022-05-11T12:16:42.000000Z 2022-07-18T09:46:15.000000Z 79
318712  156062  zzzzbov.com 2022-05-14 16:38:34 1   2022-07-17T14:10:13.000000Z flightpedia-competitors 134 11  26  2022-05-14T16:38:34.000000Z 2022-07-17T14:10:13.000000Z 278
318713 rows × 12 columns
```

Comment: notice that you have used Url: search-intelligence.co.uk/niche-finder/data-table?draw=2&columns.....url changes on each page as =2&columns..,=3&columns..,=4&columns..etc. do i need to loop through those or is there anyway to scrape whole data set at once?

Comment: Yes @PhilipFernando: that is the API endpoint accessed via XHR - you can see that in Network tab.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean to run a loop from 1 to 3188 and append scrapped data to a csv file?

Comment: @PhilipFernando I edited my answer to show how you can get all 3188 pages.

Comment: @PhilipFernando testing something now, will update - if you can get that data faster.

Comment: You should be able to get those website at a rate of 100k/call. Your mileage might vary though. Try it and let me know. @PhilipFernando

Comment: Hey Barry, I tried several times, code stopped at 100,000 records. do I need to increase the range(1,5) to higher value?

Comment: Hi Platipus Any update?

Comment: @PhilipFernando try it now. The API url also has a `start` variable - defined it now and made sure it increases for every page. The data will now contain 318713 records (all of them). Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (green checkmark under voting buttons)